# Should jquery for pulling SQL tables be in my index.php file or make a seperate file?

Tags: php, jquery

Currently I have a table from an SQL query in my index.php (see below code). I've seen some tutorials show them breaking up the HTML and PHP into 2 seperate files, while others keep them in one. Is the php code supposed to be in a separate file (ie. search.php) or does it not matter? Are there any benefits doing it either way? Thanks

```
//index.php

<div class="card shadow mb-4"  style="background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);">
                        <div class="card-header py-3" style="background-color: rgb(90, 136, 255);">
                            <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-white">Item Overview</h6>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="table-responsive" style="background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);">
                                <table class="table table-bordered"  id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th style="width: 10%; color:black">Manufacturer</th>
                                            <th style="width: 10%; color:black">Parent</th>
                                            <th style="width: 10%; color:black">Catalog Number</th>
                                            <th style="width: 43%; color:black">Description</th>
                                            <th style="width: 5%; color:black">UOM</th>
                                            <th style="width: 5%; color:black">Conversion</th>
                                            <th style="width: 5%; color:black">Average Price</th>
                                            <th style="width: 7%; color:black">Best Price</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody id="firstcontents">
                                                                      
<?php
    require_once "db.php";
    if(isset($_GET['term']))
        {   

        $term = '%' . $_GET['term'] . '%';
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM Main_Search WHERE SearchName LIKE ? LIMIT 10";
      

        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql); 
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $term);   
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
          while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<td>" . $row["MFG_Simple"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["Parent"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["MFG_Item_ID"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["Description"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["UOM"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["Conversion"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . "$ " . $row["Average_Price"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . "$ " . $row["Best_Price"] . "</td>";
"</tr>";
             }
      
         }
         $conn->close();
         
?>        
         
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
```

Comment: You will never be able to seperate the php and html entirely.  That being said, you should definetly try to seperate the logic from your template. In your example, you should at least have a seperate file containing a class that is able to connect to your database and perform db operations. Then wherever you need it you use that class to fetch data from your db. You will still need php in your template to e.g. loop through the data and accessing the data itself. In most php frameworks there is some sort of MVC (Model View Controller) design patter used to structure your program.

Comment: @Lapskaus Thank you! That was exactly the answer I was looking for!